# Convert Ant build file to Makefile

Tags: xslt, ant, makefile, docbook

I have Ant build file which is used in Docbook. Now I am going to convert that Ant build file to a Makefile which uses Xsltproc processor. I am not particularly familiar with either Makefile or Ant. So please help me to  convert it. Are there any resources which I should follow?

Here I want to,
1. copy folder structure and its content into another folder
2. configure java system properties
3. configure classpath

In ant script, it has code like this,

```
<copy todir="${output-dir}">
<fileset dir="${ant.file.dir}/template">
<include name="**/*"/>
</fileset>
</copy>

 <java classname="com.nexwave.nquindexer.IndexerMain" fork="true"> 
         <sysproperty key="htmlDir" value="${output-dir}/content"/>
         <sysproperty key="htmlExtension" value="${html.extension}"/>
           <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="${xercesImpl.jar}"/>         
        <pathelement location="/usr/share/xml-commons/lib/xml-apis.jar"/>    
      </classpath>
    </java>
```

I want to convert above 2 codes in make.
Thank you..!!

Comment: For Docbook consider using the Docbkx Maven Plugin instead, it integrates the whole Docbook tool chain (parser, dtd, stylesheets...) into a very simple build configuration: http://code.google.com/p/docbkx-tools

Comment: Thank you..But I need to convert ant script to a Makefile. Not for maven. What shouls I do for that conversion part. I think I have to do that in hand. if you can please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make and ANT are very different technologies. Your requirement would difficult to fufil for all but the simplest use cases.

Here are some of the technical challenges:

- ANT is not Make. On the surface it looks similar, but underneath works quite differently.
- Surprisingly make is not very cross platform. Different flavours have subtle differences that could break an ANT to Makefile convertor.
- ANT is designed to support Java programs, this means it has a rich syntax for managing nasty things like Java classpaths. Again difficult to translate.

## Update

The following ANT [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

```
 <java classname="com.nexwave.nquindexer.IndexerMain" fork="true"> 
         <sysproperty key="htmlDir" value="${output-dir}/content"/>
         <sysproperty key="htmlExtension" value="${html.extension}"/>
           <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="${xercesImpl.jar}"/>         
        <pathelement location="/usr/share/xml-commons/lib/xml-apis.jar"/>    
      </classpath>
 </java>
```

can be translated into the following unix java command-line.

```
java \
   -DhtmlDir=$PUT_OUTPUT_DIR_HERE \
   -DhtmlExtension=$PUT_EXT_HERE \
   -cp $CLASSPATH:$PATH_TO_XERCES_JAR:/usr/share/xml-commons/lib/xml-apis.jar \
   com.nexwave.nquindexer.IndexerMain
```

Comment: thanks. I know it is difficult.. but I have to do that for a project. I have 4 jar files and have to add them to the classpath. If you can please give me a code to add those jar files to classpath in a makefile.

Comment: @harsh Sorry can't write the Makefile logic for you, but I did provide an example of how to translate the ANT java task into a Unix command-line.

Comment: @ Mark: Thank you very much..That is the code I was looking for. I have finished copying and have to finished only java task. I set my java task as below

java \

 -DhtmlDir=docsrc \

 -DindexerLanguage=en \

 -DhtmlExtension=html \

 -DdoStem=true \

 -cp $CLASSPATH:$(DOCBOOK_STYLES)/webhelpindexer.jar:$(DOCBOOK_STYLES)/lucene-analyzers-3.0.0.jar:$(DOCBOOK_STYLES)/lucene-core-3.0.0.jar \

 com.nexwave.nquindexer.IndexerMain \

But it gives error saying 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/nexwave/nquindexer/IndexerMain"

Comment: When I set only webhelpindexer.jar into class path, it doesn't give that error. Error happened only when several jar files are added. 
BTW what did you meant by $CLASSPATH variable. Do I need to add any path to that variable. Please tell me, since I am very new to this stuff.

Comment: It's not uncommon for Unix admins to pre-configure a common CLASSPATH variable, containing common jars. I'm personally allergic to the idea as I think every Java program should manage it's own classpath.