# Make alternative for an Ant xslt task

Tags: xslt, ant, makefile

I am going to convert an Ant script to a Make file. I have finished lot of conversion part of it. But that ant script has small code like below,

```
<xslt
  in=""
    out=""
    style="../profiling/profile.xsl">
  <param name="profile.arch" expression="${profile.arch}" if="profile.arch"/>
  <param name="profile.audience" expression="${profile.audience}" if="profile.audience"/>
</xslt>
```

How should I write above "xslt", "in", "out", "style", and "param name" parts of ant script in my Make file? Can any one give me a sample Make file code for it?
I tried and searched about that conversion so many times, but I couldn't find it.

Thank you..!!

Comment: Whyever would you want to convert an Ant build to make in the firstplace ?

Comment: Hi, I have joined to open source project and there I have to convert a Ant script to a Make file for Make users. I have finished lot of portion of that conversion. But I couldn't finished only above part..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Ant build file to Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810236/convert-ant-build-file-to-makefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make doesn't have an XSLT transformation program built in. When converting the [xslt ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) one must chose which program to substitute.

ANT has [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html) built in. The java jars would need to be first installed. Here is how you could download them from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org):

```
curl -O http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar
curl -O http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar
```

Running the following java program would perform the desired XSLT transformation:

```
java -cp xalan-2.7.1.jar:serializer-2.7.1.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process \
     -IN inputData.xml \
     -XSL ../profiling/profile.xsl \
     -OUT outputFile.html \
     -PARAM profile.arch ??? \
     -PARAM profile.audience ???
```

See [Xalan documentation](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mark..Sorry for late reply. That is what I exactly wanted..=) Thank you very much..